# Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl' while running ng build --output-hashing=all --prod

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-validation

Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl' while running `ng build --output-hashing=all --prod` however, for the `ng build` everything works fine

I have the below form group

```
export class TestCenterLocationStep2Component extends BaseFormComponent<any> implements OnInit {
    this.$form = this.fb.group({
          email: [this.step2.email || '', [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$')]],
          phone: [this.step2.phone || ''],
          configuration: this.fb.group({
    
            sessionOpenDays: [this.step2.configuration.sessionOpenDays || '', Validators.required],
            sessionOpenHours: [this.step2.configuration.sessionOpenHours || '', Validators.required],
            sessionOpenMinutes: [this.step2.configuration.sessionOpenMinutes || '', Validators.required],
    
            sessionCloseDays: [this.step2.configuration.sessionCloseDays || '', Validators.required],
            sessionCloseHours: [this.step2.configuration.sessionCloseHours || '', Validators.required],
            sessionCloseMinutes: [this.step2.configuration.sessionCloseMinutes || '', Validators.required],
    
            applicationExpiryDays: [this.step2.configuration.applicationExpiryDays || '', Validators.required],
            applicationExpiryHours: [this.step2.configuration.applicationExpiryHours || '', Validators.required],
            applicationExpiryMinutes: [this.step2.configuration.applicationExpiryMinutes || '', Validators.required],
    
            paymentCloseDays: [this.step2.configuration.paymentCloseDays || '', Validators.required],
            paymentCloseHours: [this.step2.configuration.paymentCloseHours || '', Validators.required],
            paymentCloseMinutes: [this.step2.configuration.paymentCloseMinutes || '', Validators.required]
          })
        });
}
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="$form" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()" *ngIf="$form" novalidate>
    <div class="mt-3" formGroupName="configuration">
        <div class="form-group row w-100 pr-5">
            <label for="sessionOpenDays"
                class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Days</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <select class="form-control" id="sessionOpenDays"
                    formControlName="sessionOpenDays"
                    [class.is-invalid]="(!$form.controls.configuration.controls.sessionOpenDays.valid && $form.controls.configuration.controls.sessionOpenDays.touched) || (!$form.controls.configuration.controls.sessionOpenDays.valid && validate)">
                    <option value="" disabled></option>
                    <option *ngFor="let item of days" [ngValue]="item">{{item}}
                    </option>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback"
                    *ngIf="(!$form.controls.configuration.controls.sessionOpenDays.valid && $form.controls.configuration.controls.sessionOpenDays.touched) || (!$form.controls.configuration.controls.sessionOpenDays.valid && validate)">
                    Required</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

FormGroup

```
export abstract class BaseFormComponent<T> {
  @Output() $form: FormGroup;
}
```

Getting an exception as

```
src/app/testCentres/test-centre-locations/test-center-location-step2/test-center-location-step2.component.html(58,53): Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
```

while running the command `ng build --output-hashing=all --prod`, however, for the ng build everything works fine

Comment: Complete guess for now. What about if you add after `configuration: this.fb.group({ ... })` this additional type: `as FormGroup`?

Comment: @GytisTG no it didn't work

Comment: How is `this.$form` (type) defined?

Comment: It is defined in another abstract class and extends by the main class. updated the code please have a look

Comment: Hmm, not sure... I tested similar thing in my local server and I seem to be not getting this error. I'm a bit tempted to use `any` as a last measurement.

Comment: No luck, still the same issue

Comment: Even with this example? https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vkid5t?file=index.ts (ignore errors, I copied only the component part)

Comment: Your validators are completely misconfigured just so you know.

Comment: What does that mean, completely misconfigured

Answer (score 0):

After changing

```
[class.is-invalid]="(!$form.controls.configuration.controls.sessionOpenDays.valid && $form.controls.configuration.controls.sessionOpenDays.touched) || (!$form.controls.configuration.controls.sessionOpenDays.valid && validate)"

<div class="invalid-feedback"
                    *ngIf="(!$form.controls.configuration.controls.sessionOpenDays.valid && $form.controls.configuration.controls.sessionOpenDays.touched) || (!$form.controls.configuration.controls.sessionOpenDays.valid && validate)">
                    Required</div>
```

To

```
[ngClass]="{'switchError': (!$form.get('configuration').get('idTypesAccepted').valid && $form.get('configuration').get('idTypesAccepted').touched) || (!$form.get('configuration').get('idTypesAccepted').valid && validate)}"


    <div class="text-danger" style="font-size: 12px;"
        *ngIf="(!$form.get('configuration').get('idTypesAccepted').valid && $form.get('configuration').get('idTypesAccepted').touched) || (!$form.get('configuration').get('idTypesAccepted').valid && validate)">
  At least one must be selected</div>
```